# Any way to remove children of a specific component in jsf?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm working in jsf 1.2 and icefaces 1.8

I have a popup and there I'm building a wizard.

Using a c:forEach I'm showing some inputs for the user in step 2. The issue is that when going back to step 1, choose another option and show another set of inputs in step 2 some of the **initial ids of input components** are kept...

Is there any way I can remove the children of the main div?

My structure is like:

```
    <ice:panelGroup binding="#{addServiceResourcesBean.wrapperDiv}">

      <c:forEach
                    var="index"
                    begin="0"
                    end="#{addServiceResourcesBean.attribsListSize}"
                    step="1"
                    varStatus="status">

          //inputs rendered
     </c:forEach>
    </ice:panelGroup>
```

I just hope that removing all the children from wrapperDiv will force jsf cycle to re-create them from scratch with other ids...

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me, just call `getChildren` and then `clear`:

```xml
<h:form id="form1">
  <h:panelGroup id="panel1">
      .... forEach ...

  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

```java
String clientId = "form1:panel1";
UIComponent comp = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(clientId);
// here there is the call
comp.getChildren().clear();
```